# Chef attribute node[:languages] vanishes after first chef-client run

Tags: apache2, passenger, chef-infra

I have a Chef cookbook that includes the `passenger_apache2::mod_rails` recipe from the [passenger_apache2 cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/passenger_apache2). On the server's first Chef run, this created two (valid) configuration files:

```
# /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

# /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
PassengerMaxPoolSize 6
```

These are created by using the cookbook's templates [passenger.load.erb](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/passenger_apache2/blob/master/templates/default/passenger.load.erb) and [passenger.conf.erb](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/passenger_apache2/blob/master/templates/default/passenger.conf.erb), respectively, using `node[:languages][:ruby][:ruby_bin]` and `node[:languages][:ruby][:gems_dir]`. Those attributes are be [automatically populated by Ohai](http://docs.opscode.com/ohai.html).

On a second run of `chef-client`, these files get screwed up. Here's how they look now:

```
# /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

# /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf
PassengerRoot /gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby 
PassengerMaxPoolSize 6
```

So it appears that `node[:languages][:ruby]` is not getting populated during the Chef run. But if I call Ohai directly from an IRB session on the server, it appears correctly.

```rb
$ sudo -Hu root /usr/bin/irb1.9.1
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
irb(main):002:0> require 'chef'
irb(main):003:0> node = YAML::load(`/usr/local/bin/ohai`)
irb(main):004:0> node['languages']['ruby']['ruby_bin']
=> "/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1"
irb(main):005:0> mash = Chef::Mash.new(node)
irb(main):006:0> mash[:languages][:ruby][:ruby_bin]
=> "/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1"
```

I can fix the file, but it won't stop the problem from recurring on the next Chef run. I'm a bit stumped on how to appropriately troubleshoot this problem further.

Has anyone else run into this problem? I haven't yet tried setting those attributes manually in my cookbook or role, but I don't believe I should; automatic attributes are not supposed to be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved this by just restarting chef-client, but I'm still stumped on the root cause.

I believe that (at the time I experienced this problem) the running instance of the chef-client daemon was the original instance started when I bootstrapped the server with `knife bootstrap`. Our bootstrap template installs the ruby1.9.1 package, but maybe the chef-client daemon failed to load it properly. (I'm fuzzy on this.)

I first tried adding `ohai "reload"` to my recipes, and on the next scheduled Chef run, the configuration files were still broken.

Next I ran `service chef-client restart`, and then Chef populated the configuration files in question correctly. On the next run, they were still correct.

So I am hoping this goes away, but I'm still befuddled why my running chef-client instance wasn't capable of reloading automatic attributes from Ohai correctly. If anyone with deeper operational knowledge of Chef comes across this, I still welcome any comments or war stories.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - I plan to, as soon as the time limit is up.